# How to handle user authentication popup in Mobile/Tablet

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I am developing automation scripts using selenium webdirver, Appium for Mobile website automation.

Previously for the website I automate there is no authentication popup asked.
Now for all the lower environments authentication is asked.

So how do I handle user authentication popup.

Technologies I use are java, selenium and appium for both Android and iOS platforms.

Can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can get xpath/id of popup element and buttons , using these you can perform action on these buttons.

```
@findby(id="android/button1")
WebElement allow_button;

public void clickonAllow()
{

    allow_button.click();

}
```

As per requirement you can click on button "Allow" / "Deny" or "Accept" or "Reject"

In web you can try `driver.switchTo().alert().accept();` or `driver.switchTo().alert().deny();`

Comment: Hi @Shiv first of all thanks for your reply. If the user authentication is browser based how can I write an xpath for that

Comment: While accessing website it asks for a user authentication. Without entering proper user name and password I cannot proceed further. Since this authentication popup doesn't have a html structure behind it I am not able to handle it..

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue just a while ago, with allowing locations.
This issue should be divided into platform specific

for iOS is bit more specific and it has code like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeAlert//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name='Allow']")).click();
```

(if You have for eg. 'Allow' button)

and for Android You can break them into elements, here is a code example from my code:

```
public class Alert implements org.openqa.selenium.Alert
    @AndroidFindBy(id = "com.android.packageinstaller:id/dialog_container")
    @WithTimeout(time = 3, unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    public MobileElement alertControl;

    @AndroidFindBy(id = "com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_message")
    @WithTimeout(time = 3, unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    private MobileElement content;

    @AndroidFindBy(id = "com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button")
    @WithTimeout(time = 3, unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    private MobileElement buttonAccept;

    @AndroidFindBy(id = "com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_deny_button")
    @WithTimeout(time = 3, unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    private MobileElement buttonDismiss;


    public Alert(SessionInfo sessionInfo){
        super(sessionInfo);
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(sessionInfo.getMobileDriver(), 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS), this)

      WaitUtils.isElementPresent(sessionInfo.getMobileDriver(),alertControl,2);

        if (!Util.areElementsLoaded(alertControl, content, buttonAccept, buttonDismiss)) {
            setLoaded(false);
        } else {
            setLoaded(true);
        }
        Validate.isScreenLoaded(getSessionInfo(), this.isLoaded());

    }


    @Override
    public void dismiss() {
        buttonDismiss.click();
        Validate.action(getSessionInfo(), "ALERT - click button 'Dismiss'");
    }

    @Override
    public void accept() {
        buttonAccept.click();
        Validate.action(getSessionInfo(), "ALERT - click button 'Accept'");
    }

    @Override
    public String getText() {
        String value = content.getText();
        Validate.action(getSessionInfo(), "ALERT - get content");
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public void sendKeys(String s) {

    }
```